# SimulationX - Records

Tags: vba, record, modelica, simulationx

this question is for SimulationX users:

How can I link to any Record entry within a Model structure (.isx file)?

Is it not possible to set a Record entry as source for a parameter field (real) in SimX?

The Record Entry is filled with a vector algorithm, as follows:
[image: Vector to Record Entry]

Variable value of Record:

```
XY.XY.Records.xBore(*x1=1,x2=2,x3=3*,x4=0,x5=0,x6=0,x7=0,x8=0,x9=0,x10=0,x11=0,x12=0,x13=0,x14=0,x15=0,x16=0,x17=0,x18=0,x19=0,x20=0)
```

This block can only be copied manually by the user, I tried to circumvent by a VBA copy script but it is useless, since the script only copies string values of the exact value.
If possible also a VBA script would be helpful which copies the field in principle, but without project specific values (these records entries vary with each project).

VBA code:

```
ActiveDocument.Parameters("DamperType.xBore").Value="XY.XY.Records.xBore(x1=0.071000000000000008,x2=0.158,x3=0.23400000000000001,x4=0.29399999999999998,x5=0.33800000000000002,x6=0.36499999999999999,x7=0.39500000000000002,x8=0,x9=0,x10=0,x11=0,x12=0,x13=0,x14=0,x15=0,x16=0,x17=0,x18=0,x19=0,x20=0)"
```